# How to convert date and time string to time ago type?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to in firebase and android also.
In my app students can share his question and answer about syllabus.
For this i set the time time and date string in firebase database and by the POJO class i retrieve the date and time in String format like Date: 06-April-2019 and time:01:38:24.
Till now i used setText in TextView by model.getTime and model.getDate.
So this like be a update(TextView) 06-April-2019 01:38:24
now i want to chnage it by Timeago like minute ago, hour ago, day ago, month ago, year ago

Sorry for bad english.
and thanx in advance

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final question model)
        {

final String PostKey=getRef(position).getKey();//get key by this line

        holder.userfullname.setText(model.getFirstname()+" "+model.getLastname());
        holder.time.setText(" "+model.getTime());//***TextView 06-April-2019*** 
        holder.date.setText(" "+model.getDate());//*TextView 01:38:24*
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With System.currentTimeMillis(); you get the Milliseconds they have passed since 1/1/1970 as long.

So what u wand we can achieve with 2 more custom functions in your adapter.

The first one take ur date and time and convert it to miliseconds.

```js
private long millisFromDateAndTime(String date, String time){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
        try
        {
            Date mDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            Date mTime = timeFormat.parse(time);
            long dateInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
            long timeInMilliseconds = mTime.getTime();
            return timeInMilliseconds + dateInMilliseconds;
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The second function takes this miliseconds from when the post was made and return a String that contains how much time ago this was.

```js
private String timeAgo(long startTime){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeDifference = (currentTime - startTime) / 1000;
        Log.d("!!!!DIFF!!!!!!", String.valueOf(timeDifference));
        long timeUnit;

        if(timeDifference < 60){
            timeUnit = DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
        } else if(timeDifference < 3600){
            timeUnit = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
        } else if (timeDifference < 86400){
            timeUnit = DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
        }else if (timeDifference < 31536000){
            timeUnit = DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        } else {
            timeUnit = DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS;
        }

        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(startTime, currentTime,
                timeUnit, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);

        return String.valueOf(timeAgo);
    }
```

You can place this two funtions in the bottom of your Adapter.

Finally you will use this function in onBindViewholder.

```js
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final question model)
        {

final String PostKey=getRef(position).getKey();//get key by this line

        holder.userfullname.setText(model.getFirstname()+" "+model.getLastname());
        //Convert your Date and Time to milliseconds
        long startTime = millisFromDateAndTime(model.getDate(), model.getTime);
        //Set the timeAgo text in the Textview of your choice
        holder.time.setText(timeAgo(startTime));
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
        }
```

Good Luck, tell me if it worked.

Comment: can help me with coding

Comment: If you would post some code i can do this. Post at least where u save the time and then where u reuse it.